# Store full date or just an year in Database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am working on a project where there are bunch of dates which I need to store in a database (MySQL).

The problem is, some dates are full, but some dates are just only year.

For example, the dates are like this:

- 20 January 1980
- 2011
- 25 February 2012
- 2008

I am using the function `date()` and `strtotime()` function in PHP to convert the dates in `Y-m-d` format. The full dates are converted successfully, but the dates with just only an year is converted to today's date which is wrong.

The questions are:

- How to successfully determine which is a full date and which is just only an year in PHP and then apply the `date()` and `strtotime()` function to the full date only?
- How to save these variations (full date and only year) in database? (if it is possible in a single column)
- While fetching from the database, how to know whether the date is full or just an year and display it accordingly?

**Edit:**

Confused. I will be doing operations on date such as sorting date-wise which will include both full and year only dates. Whether to:

- Store year as 1990-00-00 and check for the zeroes while retrieving?
- Store year as 1990-01-01 and another boolean field isYear?
- Store year, month and day as integers in different columns?

Comment: Use PHP's `\DateTime` and MySQL's `DATETIME`, don't do this messy string stuff from the stone age.

Comment: Many options make for a harder choice :-) Don't worry. None of the three options given is really bad. Just pick the one you think may be best and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a given string only specifies a year by passing it to [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$s = '2014';
if (date_create_from_format('Y', $s))
    $t = strtotime($s.'-01-01');
else
    $t = strtotime($s);

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t);
```

Answer (score 3):

In a database you store the objects you are dealing with. You can store names like 'John Smith' just as it is or you store first and last name separately (but where to put the middle name then? :-) It depends on your requirements. For one system it is necessary to filter and sort by last names, so last name must be a separate column. Another system may only be interested in the full name without the worries to bother which in "Wu Chang" is the first and which is the last name.

Same here. Usually one stores dates as a DATE or DATETIME column. But you are interested in the year where day and month can be unknown. So you store these separately. The year probably with a NOT NULL constraint, and day and month nullable.

I recommend separate integer columns for year month and day. Don't use a string with some format one must know and which may be broken every now and then.

EDIT: I just notice I haven't answered your PHP question: Well, when you get a string that consists of four digits it's a year, else you can either convert it to date, then it's a date, or you can't, then it's invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use zeroes on the unknown parts of the date. So insert '2014-00-00' instead of just 2014.

Comment: Is this date like 2014-00-00 acceptable in MySQL database? If yes, then how to determine whether the date is just an year or full date in PHP before performing this operation?

Comment: Yes, this is acceptable, that's the beauty of it, you can just use your existing column.
You could add -00-00 to dates that are only years. When you SELECT it you could check if it ends with -00-00 to see that it is a year instead of a full date.

Comment: It can be acceptable depending on your MySQL install. Look up modes like ALLOW_INVALID_DATES, NO_ZERO_DATE, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's a number. If true then it's a year. So add "01/01/" before converting it to a date. It will be considered as being an event for january first. You need a separate field isYear (a boolean) to determine wether it is a year or a date.

Answer (score 0):

To save the different date formats in the same column in the db you would have to save them as a String. This doesn't make sense if you want to do some operations on them but is fine if you just want to display the value. That being said, if you want to perform some operations on them I suggest having 2 columns in the db, one for the full year of type TIMESTAMP and 1 for the year as type YEAR. This way you also know which type you are loading by checking which column is not null and so solving your other question.

To answer your first question, you can check which is the full date and which is only the year by checking the string length. If the trimmed string is longer than 4 chars then it must be the full date. Still I would do error handling in case you have some incorrectly formatted data sent to you.

reading other replies, i wouldn't set it to 01/01/2014 for example, because if you have an actual date of 01/01/2014 you cannot determine if it was sent as full date or the year only. Alternatively you can follow this method and add a column of type BIT to represent a boolean stating if it was fullYear

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the full dates is consistent then you can check if there is a full date by checking for spaces in the string.

Secondly, if you've got a date column in your table, you can save just the year value, and leave month and day as zeros.

```
if (strstr(trim($date), ' ') !== false) {
    // space was found, this is a full date
    $mysqlDate = /* ... strtotime, etc. */
} else {
    // space was not found, this is just a year date
    $mysqlDate = trim($date) . '-00-00';
}
```

When it comes to selecting, you can then filter year-only dates by checking for zeros in the date value.

Not a pretty solution, but the one that jumps to mind if you intend to store them all in the same column.